# Terraform resources changes configuration items every time its deployed

Tags: terraform

I have worked with both the AWS and Azure providers in terraform and both times I have experienced an issue with "toggling" configuration items.

My terraform resources look like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "sample" {
  name     = "sample"
  location = "uksouth"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sample" {
  name                     = "samplestackoverflow"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.sample.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.sample.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  min_tls_version = "TLS1_2"
}
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "sample" {
  name                = "sample"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.sample.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.sample.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "sample" {
  name                        = "samplestackoverflow"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.sample.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.sample.location
  storage_account_name        = azurerm_storage_account.sample.name
  storage_account_access_key  = azurerm_storage_account.sample.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id             = azurerm_service_plan.sample.id
  https_only                  = true
  client_certificate_mode     = "Required"
  functions_extension_version = "~4"
  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.8"
    }
  }
}
```

Now the issue itself is that every time I run `terraform apply` and there are changes to be made, for example: change https_only from `true` to `false`, the `site_config` item is removed. So if I run `terraform apply` immediatelly after those changes are made, then that `site_config` that disappeared will be re-added. The output looks like this:

```
      ~ site_config {
            # (33 unchanged attributes hidden)

          + application_stack {
              + python_version              = "3.8"
              + use_dotnet_isolated_runtime = false
            }
        }
```

As I mentioned, this happens also with other providers and resources (I remember it happening to me for AWS API Gateway too). I can of course come around this by every time `terrafrom apply` twice. But I was wondering if there was something that could be done here?

Comment: I think this thread will help you https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-not-detecting-drift-on-resources-intended-or-not/17547/5

Comment: You can for example set this argument `use_dotnet_isolated_runtime` to the value it has during the first apply and it shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are facing a TF bug, some resources are not saving all its values in the state file, that's the issue!. --In fact, I'd to raise some bugs, commonly function apps and web apps have those issues.